# Separating boundaries of Classical mechanics and Quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I had my very first class of Quantum Mechanics a few months back. The discussion was on what is the limit after which an object starts showing quantum behavior. My professor said that when an object's De-Broglie wavelength is comparable to the object's size(or the dimensions), it starts showing quantum behavior.

So, my question to him was
let us assume we have a stationary particle and 3 frames of reference.

**Frame 1** is moving at a high speed such that De-Broglie wavelength of particle is comparable to particle's dimensions. So, Frame 1 observes quantum behavior of particle.

**Frame 2** starts from rest and has a constant acceleration. So this frame would see the particle exhibit classical behavior initially(when velocity isn't high enough for particle's De-Broglie wavelength to be comparable to its dimensions) and then shift to showing quantum behavior.

**Frame 3** is at rest. So, Frame 3 observes classical behavior.

How do these 3 frames observe the same particle exhibiting different behaviors?

Note: I'm not sure what effects will it have on the first 2 frames if we consider relativistic effects. Also I'm not very confident about this idea of comparing the particle's dimensions to its De-Broglie wavelength and would appreciate any clarifications regarding the same :)

Comment: Standard QM is not relativistically invariant, so relativistic boosts are bound to lead to confusing contradictions. Your instructor did not emphasize that?

Comment: Thanks, @CosmasZachos.Not really. This was just an introductory course, so we didn't explore the relativistic aspects. He did mention that this question can be answered by Relativistic QM which is beyond my scope at the moment.

Comment: de Broglie wavelength is $h/p$, so it depends solely on object's momentum, which in turn indeed depends on the frame of observation, or speed of the object. Just having macroscopic object moving slowly enough obeys this criterion, but obviously such object is not behaving quantumly. In other words, the proposed criterion, as stated, is wrong. Maybe the teacher was thinking of cold ideal gas, where if average de Broglie wavelength of molecules becomes comparable to inter-molecular distances (not molecule size though!), the gas behaviour starts to deviate from classical theory.

Comment: Then quantum statistics becomes relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_de_Broglie_wavelength

Comment: @JánLalinský Thanks.